# Selenium python google address sidebar result

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-search

I'm new to selenium and I would like to scrape the google address search results on the sidebar column.

I know how to use selenium to search with google and land on the below page but what I want is to extract the address in the highlighted section.

[image]

I try to use inspect to get the element of that section but I'm very new to html. 
Below attach my code to print out the main section of the results. I'm only sure that this section falls within the main section.

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("saville residence")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
main = driver.find_element_by_id('main')
print(main.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if you try to search for

```
main = driver.find_element_by_id('main')
```

Your code returns everything written on the page.
I personally love to find elements by their xpath. While this approach will definitely make your code less attractive it will definitely make it more reliable too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Povilas/Documents/GitHub/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("saville residence")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
main = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/span[2]')
print(main.text)
```

After running this code my output was:
Saville Residence, Jalan Klang Lama, Taman Seputeh, 58100 Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia

Comment: Thanks! This is a good option too! I've found another way using class_name, will post the answer below :D

Comment: Yes you can search for element by a lot of things class name is one of them too. Good luck coding

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative solution using html elements:
1.'Ctrl+Shift+C' or click the icon circle in red
2. click on the target section in the webpage.

If we expand that section in the html elements, we can see the address under a **class = 'LrzXr'**.

[image]

So in code we can find element by its class name like below:

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("saville residence")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
main = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'LrzXr')
print(main.text)
```